# adding an element at the end of a list, scheme

Tags: list, loops, scheme, racket, addition

```
(define addatend(lst num)
  (cond
  [(null? lst ) num]
  [else (cons (car lst ) (addatend(cdr lst) num))]
  ))
```

I am trying to add an element to the end of the list. The program above is what I have so far. The code above is very close to what I want it to do. I cant figure out whats wrong with it.

Comment: I mean, it's not *that* close to what you're trying to do. The function body is mostly right, aside from one type error. But when you call the function, it doesn't run any of your code at all, because you've also declared the parameters wrong. So I'm not sure how you could test it enough to come to the conclusion that it's close to right.

Comment: Looks like you're confusing common lisp and schene syntax... Needs better formatting too. `addatend(lst num)` is, besides wrong syntax, looks too much like a single expression instead of two because of the missing space

Comment: The base case should be a list, no?

Comment: `(define (add-at-end lst x) (if (null? lst) (list x) (cons (car lst) (add-at-end (cdr lst) x))))` will do it. You were not that far away.